# Efficiency in common nlp tasks

Tags: java, python, nlp

I am trying to make an application that makes heavy use of pos tagging. But the pos tagging capabilities of nltk do not seem up to the mark to me - for instance :

```
import nltk
text = "Obama delivers his first speech."

sent  =  nltk.sent_tokenize(text)


loftags = []
for s in sent:
    d = nltk.word_tokenize(s)   

    print nltk.pos_tag(d)
```

Result :

akshayy@ubuntu:~/summ$ python nn1.py
[('Obama', 'NNP'), ('delivers', 'NNS'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('first', 'JJ'), ('speech', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]

This is not good as compared to Stanford NLP. Now at this moment, when I have enough invested time and efforts to Python envrionment, moving to java doesnt seem practical to me. Also, I am more inclined to C as compared to java, hence Python is closer there as well for future usage. Hence first question is:
1) Do you really think Java is better for nlp tasks with large set of tools available. I have done good research and found java has bigger community dedicated towards nlp tasks.

2) Instead, is there any good approach that I can create my own sentence parser and then pos tagger to have flexibility for modification for any language being used in future.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use one of the Java-based POS-taggers.  I use the [Stanford Core NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) tagger, but there are others.  NLTK is primarily an instructional toolkit, not intended for industrial-strength usage.  The Java-based taggers will also be much faster.

However, using a Java toolkit does not preclude you from doing your work in Python.  It is trivial to write a wrapper class in Python that simply runs the Java commands and parses the results for you to use in your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

**Python** has really great XML/HTML parsing libraries such as Beautiful Soup[6] and Scrape.py[7]. You can use these libraries to quickly scrape the web and generate large data sets to improve the performance of your models (because lets face it, big data trumps complexity)
Consider your other options: It would not make sense to use a compiled language like **C++/Java** for this type of work unless you needed to increase performance (computational speed, not model accuracy). As far as I can tell, Ruby is completely useless for any Machine Learning, Data Mining, or Natural Language Processing task. Maybe you could use Lisp, but at this point, Python has a larger eco-system.
Read more here
http://www.quora.com/What-programming-languages-are-suitable-for-natural-language-processing